# CSS Chevron Showing Unwanted Rectangle

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a chevron with a rectangular border using CSS as a "button" to transition a slideshow but I am getting a rectangle in the place that the parallelograms would have appeared if not skewed.

How can I get rid of this vertical rectangle, or at least hide it or make it the same color as the border?

Here is what it looks like with an image I grabbed from the net: http://jsfiddle.net/splunge/nmq3ayqk/

Thanks

```
<img src="http://unsplash.imgix.net/reserve/wpYap0TYQ3mElk0kRbYn_LagunaHIke.jpg?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=345&q=75&w=960">
<a tabindex="0" title="Previous Slide" alt="Previous Slide" id="slideshow-prev" href=""></a>


#slideshow-prev:before {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.3);
    content: "";
    height: 50%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform: skew(-25deg, 0deg);
    width: 100%;
}
#slideshow-prev:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.3);
    content: "";
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: skew(25deg, 0deg);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1000;
}
#slideshow-prev {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background-color: rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.3);
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 135px 20px 136px;
    height: 70px;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: I fixed the jsfiddle link so if you went to the old one please try the new link.

Comment: The rectangle is #slideshow-prev itself.  I would suggest removing all styling from the <a> tag, except whats needed to make it the correct size for you to click on.  Then, inside the <a> tag, put some <span>'s to create your geometry.

Comment: The width and padding are generating the issue. And the alpha colors for border and bg

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I went with cjspurg's solution.  Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too slow! But I took a slightly different approach than Michael, above. The center box was indeed your `slideshow-prev` element. Since the color was being created by the border, the element itself had a different background color.

I would suggest using the element itself as the bar (not the border of the element), and then positioning the chevrons with percentages, for scaling purposes.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4u835az/1/)

```
#slideshow-prev:before {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.3);
    content: "";
    height: 10%;
    left: 40%; /* position as percentages for scaling */
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    transform: skew(-25deg, 0deg);
    width: 25%;
    border: none;
}
#slideshow-prev:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.3);
    content: "";
    height: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    top: 55%;
    transform: skew(25deg, 0deg);
    width: 25%;
    z-index: -1000;
}
#slideshow-prev {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    border-image: none;
    /* border-style: solid; */
    /* border-width: 135px 20px 136px; <- remove border elements, as it could screw up other width/height calculations */
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Pasted the wrong fiddle?  Chevron appears at bottom of the box for me.  I agree with your approach however.  This slightly eludes to my suggestion for a reformat of the HTML and how the elements are styled in general in order to fit best-practices.

Comment: Whoops! My viewport was shorter. Added a container with `position:relative;` so the elements are positioned relative to the picture,  not the viewport. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

The rectangle you are seeing is the  tag with ID `#slideshow-prev`.

You can fix the aesthetics of what you are doing by making a few small changes to the selector for that ID as well as some adjustments to the positioning of the pseudoelements.  However, depending on your use-case it may be better to consider a reformat of your HTML and which elements you are using to create your styles.  More on that below the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/nmq3ayqk/3/

**CSS:**

```
#slideshow-prev:before {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.3);
    content: "";
    height: 25px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: skew(-25deg, 0deg);
    width: 100%;
}
#slideshow-prev:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.3);
    content: "";
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: skew(25deg, 0deg);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1000;
}
#slideshow-prev {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background-color: rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.3);
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 135px 20px 136px;
    height: 0px;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

By setting fixed heights on the :before and :after, and also setting the height and padding of `#slideshow-prev` to 0, we can realign your angles and get rid of the box.

---

I would also suggest two things depending on your situation to follow best practices...

If these next and previous buttons are controlling a slider, and not actually controlling a LINK to some place, then don't use the `<a>` element.  Use something else like a `<div>`, or just a `<button>`.

If these are going to actually be LINKS, then you should default the styling of your  element, and apply this fancy styling to `<span>`/s inside the `<a>` element.

Answer (score 0):

I created this CSS only chevron (left invert arrow and right arrow): http://jsfiddle.net/RCzAt/195/

```
<div class="box"></div>

.box {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 32px;
    background: #000000;
}
.box:before {
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    left: -9px;
    top: 0px;
    display: block;
    border-right: 9px solid transparent;
    border-top: 16px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 16px solid #000000;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.box::after {
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    right: -9px;
    top: 7px;
    display: block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    transform: rotate(45deg) skew(15deg,15deg);
    background: #000000;
}
```